# Shisha Veshiv'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred seventy-six?

### ?ששה ושבעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 276.

Lazy gematria is "skin."

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred seventy-five entries in this ongoing series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=4170

In the past 3000 years there were only 276 years of no wars amongst nations.

ההיסטוריונים רושמים כי במשך שלושת אלפי שנה האחרונות של ההיסטוריה, לפי כותבי קורות הימים העתיקים, היו רק **מאתים שבעים ושש שנים** בלי שום מעשי איבה ומלחמה בין האומות זו לזו

Comment: It would have been nice if the article you linked would have cited a source for that claim other than "the historians," but oh, well.

Answer (score 1):

According to some reports (that I see quoted but can't find), 276 people [died on the *Patria*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patria_disaster).